# Asynchronous function call with await/async does not work in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await

I am working with Angular, I have issues with asynchronous function call.

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.a = new A();
    await this.a.method_A();

    this.b = new B(this.a);
    this.b.method_B(this.a.data);
}

export class A {
    data;
    async method_A() {
        observable$.subscribe((data) => { this.data = data });
    }
}
```

`method_A` is an asynchronous function, so it has to be ensured that after the `method_A` is completed, `b` has to be instantiated and the `method_B` has to be invoked. So, I used `await/async` like above, but I still find that instance `b` is created before `method_A` is completed. Is there a way for those steps to be performed sequentially?

Comment: you should architect your functions & calls a bit different. your `method_B` call should be within your `.subscribe` block because what that means is: once observable emits (data is ready) > invoke `method_B` with that data. now, if there is something else going on within your `method_A` that you don't show here, for example, some other observable (http call, e.g.) then you might want to look into `switchMap, concatMap` or similar operators. The whole point of observables is to model the whole flow before it happens and then subscribe in one place. that way you don't need to `await` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async method_A() {
    observable$.subscribe((data) => { this.data = data });
}
```

`method_A` doesn't wait for `observable$` to emit. What is `observable$`, BTW? Does it emit only once? If so, you can easily convert it to the async-await pattern with

```
async method_A() {
    const data = await observable$.toPromise();
    this.data = data;
}
```

or, as `toPromise` is deprecated or will be soon,

```
async method_A() {
    const data = await firstValueFrom(observable$);
    this.data = data;
}
```

(And if `observable$` emits more than once, I suggest ditching the `async-await` pattern and just using RxJS).

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I resolved, I was very urgent, so asked quick without much research, async/await should be aligned with Promise. All article was very helpful. To use async/await, switching from observable to promise, it feel a little weird to me though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that will give you more context on `Observable` and `async`/`await` [RxJS Observable interop with Promises and Async-Await](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875).

Event though your function is marked as `async` it returns right after invocation before subscription to `observable$` can run and assign value to the `data` field. Instead of subscribing to observable you have to turn first item of the `Observable` into `Promise`, which you can then `await` and ensue that execution of `ngOnInit` continues only after `data` is set from observable:

```
export class A {
    data;
    async method_A() {
        this.data = await observable$.first().toPromise();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use await in the observable call.
For better understand check this documentation.
[https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77#:~:text=An%20async%20function%20can%20contain,and%20returns%20the%20resolved%20value](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77#:%7E:text=An%20async%20function%20can%20contain,and%20returns%20the%20resolved%20value).

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.a = new A();
    await this.a.method_A();

    this.b = new B(this.a);
    this.b.method_B(this.a.data);
}

export class A {
    data;
    async method_A() {
      await observable$.subscribe((data) => { this.data = data }); //here
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as you expect it to. You're `await`ing a subscription object, which you  get instantly anyway.